# Looking for a runnable simple android project involving startActivity, Intent of class

Tags: android

Basically I couldn't make the darn thing to work. I am looking for runnable project that do a simple startactivity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, xxx.class);
startActivity(i);
```

that's it!

I am looking for a complete project not just a code snippet. It should include all the xml files.

Comment: Please describe what exactly didn't work. Otherwise this question has no definitive answer and is therefore not suited for SOs Q&A format. Also look at the samples directory in your sdk folder, plenty of stuff there.

Comment: I already checked the SDK, there's the startActivity(intent) but it's NOT intent of class. Most are startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_XXX, Uri).    I just want to have an example that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One search on a search engine (named after a very large integer) for:

```
startActivity class
```

in the first page of results turned up [one of Lars Vogel's excellent tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html), covering all sorts of activity-starting scenarios. Section 3 covers your case.

There are several such samples in your SDK's `samples/` directory.

For the record, from my books, there are:

- [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Simple), showing starting a PreferenceActivity via an explicit Intent
- [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkMapless), showing an activity immediately starting another activity based on conditions
- [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/tree/master/12-Activities), the results of [tutorial #12](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials), showing a list of restaurants plus details of a clicked-upon restaurant

(and a handful others that are going to be much too complicated for your objective)